# error launching pamac-manager: libalpm.so.12

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

When I type `pamac` or `pamac-manager` in terminal and execute the command, I get this message: `error while loading shared libraries: libalpm.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Pamac was working until today. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

`pacman` updated to using `libalpm.so.13` but `pamac-manager` is still using `libalpm.so.12`. So if you updated `pacman` then `libalpm.so.12` is no longer on your system. Until `pamac-aur` is updated, `pamac-manager` will be broken. You can read more about it in the comments at [pamac-aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pamac-aur/).

Answer (score 3):

`pacman` was updated recently. All AUR helpers have similar issues. recompile and do a fresh install of `pamac` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`pacaur` was/is also broken due to this issue. I installed `yay` via `pacman` as a replacement for `pacaur` and it works fine